# How to install a library to use on a virtual platform like Docker/jupyter?

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib

I'm using anaconda 2 for python 2.7, I'm trying to use QuantLib for python and to do so, I've installed **Docker** container platform in order to import QuantLib library for python

Unfortunately, even so I may be able to use QuantLib and import the library, I'm unable to use matplotlib.
When I used to code with anaconda, matplotlib is imported correctly but when I'm trying to code on the notebook, matplotlib seems not to be installed

this is the message i get after typing `import matplotlib` in a Jupyter/Docker notebook:

```
    ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-25-3d3962ebf68c> in <module>()
      1 #! C:/users/[...]/anaconda2/lib/site-packages
----> 2 import matplotlib

ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

As docker doesn't have any folder on my computer, how can I install any missing library in order to use them in my Docker notebook ?
All explanations are used for Linux but I'm using windows 7 I coudn't find documentation about library setup in Docker.

I know Docker works with containers but I don't really understand the documentation, does anybody know how do we handle those containers to get libraries we need to install for our project ?

Thank you very much for your attention,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you are NOT using your python installation when doing this, you are using the python installation from your docker container.

Since you are on Windows, this looks a bit like this :

Windows -> Virtual linux -> Another (smaller) virtual linux (your docker container) -> python

This python cannot see the libraries installed on your windows.

Normally, you should modify your dockerfile in order to add missing libraries, however, I think you could use one of Jupyter's feature to open a terminal directly in your docker, and run pip commands directly from there.

IIRC, you can use the "new" menu when on the file browser in jupyter to do this

Comment: I see I just noticed there's a terminal, thank you very much for your help!